# "Your JSON is not valid. Error: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 6" (Firefox addon)?

Tags: json, firefox, firefox-addon, manifest

I am trying to learn how to create an add on for Firefox. I created this manifest.json file, icons, and a popup.html but I keep getting the error of "Your JSON is not valid.  Error: Unexpected token : in JSON at position 6" when I attempt to load the zip file (manifest.json, icons, html) locally/manually into my Firefox browser. What is "position 6"? Why doesn't the error tell me the line number of the error in the json file?

What is going on? This is just a simple manifest.json. I have this working in Chrome complete with a content script but I am just trying to learn how to get an addon working with Firefox, thus the simplicity of this JSON manifest file.

```
"name":"My First Firefox Extension",
"description":"My Firest Firefox Test Extension",
"manifest_version": 2,
"browser_action": 
 {
  "icons": 
  {
   "16":"icons/upsellblockicon16x16.png",
   "32":"icons/upsellblockicon32x32.png",
   "48":"icons/upsellblockicon32x32.png"
  },
  "default_popup":"html/popup.html"
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to start and finisht with {}, and the first 3 properties are mandatory

```
{
  "name":"My First Firefox Extension",
  "description":"My Firest Firefox Test Extension",
  "manifest_version": 2,
   "browser_action": {
 }
  .....
}
```

Comment: Doh! Wow do I feel stupid! I added the { } as you pointed out. Got another error that was easy to fix: i needed to add "version": "1.0" for my extension version. Then got another error, easy fix: I was using the word Firefox in my json and that is not allowed (can not use Firefox or Mozilla trademark names in json files); removed the use of Firefox, and now my addon was validated as okay. Next step is to add the content script info to the json file. Thank you Serge!!!

Comment: Oh, yeah, I am new to stackoverflow and did not even know about clicking the checkmark to accept an answer! I just did that.